# Check for matching columns and sum values over

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as such:

DF1:

| Name | Age | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 55 |
| B | 21 | 60 |
| C | 22 | 20 |
| D | 23 | 25 |
| E | 24 | 30 |

The second dataframe will contain similar data but with less info. Crucially, all the names in the the second dataframe are in the first one and I am taking a **big** assumption that all names in df1 are unique.

DF2:

| Name | Age | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 |
| D | 23 | 40 |
| E | 24 | 80 |

What I would like to do is go over the second dataframe, find the name that matches in the first dataframe and sum the scores up such that I would end up with the following dataframe:

| Name | Age | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 75 |
| B | 21 | 60 |
| C | 22 | 20 |
| D | 23 | 65 |
| E | 24 | 110 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregation - here if all another columns are summed:

```
out = pd.concat([DF1, DF2]).groupby(['Name','Age'], as_index=False).sum()
print (out)
  Name  Age  Score
0    A   20     75
1    B   21     60
2    C   22     20
3    D   23     65
4    E   24    110
```

If need specify multiple aggregation functions - here first value per groups by `Class` and another columns aggregate `sum` add [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = {'Class':'first', 'Score':'sum', 'Att.':'sum', 'Test':'sum'}
out = pd.concat([DF1, DF2]).groupby(['Name','Age'], as_index=False).agg(d)
print (out)

  Name  Age Class  Score  Att.  Test
0    A   20   ENG     60    35    55
1    B   19   ENG     45    15    60
```

Comment: @ancalleja - All columns are summed?

Comment: That works, however what if I have other columns which the values do match, I do not want to add up and I would want to keep the value in the first dataframe

Comment: That's perfection. Thanks